# AudioBufferList with two Buffers

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, cmsamplebuffer, audiobufferlist

I am receiving this ABSD from CMSampleBuffer which comes from a broadcasting session from the ReplayKit in iOS.

```
mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
mFormatFlags =  14,
mChannelsPerFrame = 2,
mBytesPerPacket =  4
mFramesPerPacket = 1
mBytesPerFrame =  4
mBitsPerChannel =  16
mSampleRate = 44100
```

The AudioBufferList has mNumberOfBuffers = 1 and mNumberOfChannels = 2.

I need to pass to the encode and transmit session  an AudiobufferList with the same ABSD but with mNumberOfBuffers = 2 and with mNumberOfChannels = 1 for each buffer.

From the specifications of the streaming session I have the following instructions:

"The audio samples are copied by the enqueueAudioBuffer method synchronously to internal buffers. The timestamp must have a valid mHostTime field.
The audio buffer must contain floating point deinterleaved samples matching the session's channel count and sample rate."

The audio I play in the app is garbled.And I think the reason is the number of channels are not matching with the session's channels .

I am new in Core Audio in iOS.

Please, how I can change the AudiBufferList to two Buffers with one Channel each one?

Thanks

Comment: How is `sampleBuffer` created?

Comment: I think that cmsamplebuffer comes with the audio compressed and I have to send it uncompressed because mFramesPerPacket must be set to 1.

Comment: The Cmsamplebuffer comes from a Broadcasting session from RepplayKit.

Comment: You could try using `AVAudioConverter` to deinterleave the audio.